# How can I simulate a path that no longer exists to let python uninstall?

Tags: python, uninstallation

I installed python and then changed the `c:/user/(username)` of my computer.

After that I am unable to unistall/repair/modify python. I tired to downgrade and upgrade but failed with error windows cannot find the path.

[image]

How can I fix this? The version which was installed is 3.7.5 and I want to install the same or the lower versions.

> edit:  I tried to create a folder same from the error but it did not work. I tried to manually remove the python files too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `mklink` utility.

```
mlkink C:\Users\vishn C:\Users\<yournewdir>
```

It's a hack, but it should let your system work through the python repair / modify / etc. problems.

When you're done, remove the "C:\Users\Vishn"; it won't delete the thing it points to, only the shortcut.

Comment: Try running from a command prompt under Administrator privileges.

Comment: It didnt work. I am from admin account but got error 'Access Denied'

Comment: Yes, being admin still means you'll need to run the terminal as administrator (right click -> Run As)

Answer (score 0):

Finally did it with help of a third party application called Revo uninstaller.